# Error: unrecognized symbol type ""

Tags: assembly, arm

My arm code:

```
                .text
                .section .rodata
format_string:
                .string "%d\n"
                .align 4
                .data
data:
                .space 8
                .globl main
                .type main, @function
main:
                ldr r11, data
                sub r2, r11, #0
                push {r2}
                ldr r2, #3
                push {r2}
                pop {r2}
                ldr r2, [r2]
                push {r2}
                pop {r2}
                pop {r3}
```

is throwing the following error:

```
test.s: Assembler messages:
test.s:10: Error: unrecognized symbol type ""
```

why?

Comment: I'm using the double quotes that my keyboard has, how am I supposed to control that?

Comment: Im using pycharm in lubuntu vm on a mac osx

Comment: I saw the smart quotes in the title of your question but I didn't notice that they were different from your code. I thought they were the same, which suggests the quotes are not the problem. You may want to change the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Because some of the characters used in these syntaxes (such as `@` and `#`) are comment characters for some architectures, some of the syntaxes below do not work on all architectures.](https://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Type.html#Type)

In the ARM syntax, `@` is a comment marker, so as the assembler is cryptically telling you, it sees an empty symbol type and barfs on the incomplete directive.

Answer (score 2):

In ARM arch, the separator `%` works
like this:

```
.type main, %function
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong.

`.type main,@function`

You need the comma